# Unicode characters in string

Tags: c#, .net, string, unicode, character-encoding

I want to get the characters of Unicode in C#

e.g

```
char ch1 = '\u2085';  
char ch2 = '\u2086';
char ch3 = '\u2087';
char ch4 = '\u2088';
char ch5 = '\u2089';
```

but it return boxes instead of symbols (₈ ₇ ₆ ₅)

How to return the symbols?

Comment: "[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)"

Comment: You can find this post useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162116/outputting-a-unicode-character-in-c-sharp

Comment: And this also helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055659/c-sharp-unicode-string-output

Comment: Since we are pasting links. Jon Skeet has quite a short but insightful piece on C# handling of unicode http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Unicode.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those characters are correctly identifying the unicode characters, but whatever medium you're rendering those characters into is not rendering them correctly.  I just tried outputting the characters in your code into a LINQPad window, and it comes out as unicode.

```
char ch1 = '\u2085';  
char ch2 = '\u8328';
char ch3 = '\u8327';
char ch4 = '\u8326';
char ch5 = '\u8325';
Console.WriteLine("" + ch1 + ch2 + ch3 + ch4 + ch5);
```

Output:

> ₅茨茧茦茥

Comment: When characters appear as small boxes, it’s usually a font problem: the font used does not contain glyphs for them. [Font support to subscript characters](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2080/fontsupport.htm) is relatively limited.