# How do I print the graphical representation of a Unicode character (BELL) using its byte value?

Tags: c#

I am trying to print a bell character to the console in C#.

See: http://graphemica.com/%F0%9F%94%94

the same website also lists:

```
JavaScript and JSON \u1F514
C, C++, and Java    \u1F514
Python              \u1F514
Perl                \x{1F514}
Ruby                \u{1F514}
CSS                 \01F514
```

So I tried:

```
Console.WriteLine("\u1F514");
```

The forum question: 
[Outputting a Unicode character in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162116/outputting-a-unicode-character-in-c-sharp) recommends MS Reference Sans Serif font for the console. When I try my console properties I only find the options Consolas and Lucida Console.

Comment: Your "source code" isn't really source code. Why not show what you have attempted?

Comment: He is asking: "How do I print the graphical representation of a Unicode character using its byte value?"