# Symbols and encoding: what symbol is this?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, special-characters, symbols, undefined-symbol

I'm working with a large text file filled with data. Different data blocks there are spitted by a symbol (or a pair of similar symbols) that looks kinda strange and weird.
I need to find out, what symbol this is, to properly (!) use it for splitting data blocks when I read the data file. Could you assist me with that?

Here is how the pair of symbols look in Stackoverflow "Ask Question" editing field:

Next I add some pics of how different the symbol looks from place to place:

In original data file

[image]

In Brackets Editor (with all the available encodings, it's the same)

[image]

In Brave Browser search bar

[image]

In Visual Studio 2019

[image]

In Stackoverflow (it's different when I type and when in the posted question) editing field

[image]

Somewhere it is converted to one of the following

[image]

While reading the symbol using C# with Encoding.UTF8 encoding, the console gives next result:
[image]

But when using Encoding.Unicode, the console gives an infinite set of smth like this:

[image]

What exactly do I have to write to make my C# code recognize and react to that symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this [unicode char finder](https://babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html) to find out what the characters are.

in order they are...

U+0003 :  END OF TEXT [ETX]

U+0001 :  START OF HEADING [SOH]

Comment: Just noticed you can't see the characters in the text field above, looks like you have to go into the edit mode to be able to copy/paste or even just see them. I think these are some of the few "zero width" characters in unicode.

Comment: Oh, thank you! Could you please give me a hit of how do I actually use it? Like, I read the line from file, and if it contains the symbols, I break, for example. How do I write them In my code (Python or C#)?

Comment: python can print unicode characters natively. this post details how you do it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569438/how-to-print-unicode-character-in-python

Comment: I got some results with C#, gonna add them to the question...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162116/outputting-a-unicode-character-in-c-sharp